# Updating XML file on Android

Tags: android

I am fairly new at developing for Android and was hoping to get some help with something.

First, just a brief idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Within the app I am developing, the user can create a project profile for each new project he starts. I have already created the code to create a new XML file for each new project which is stored on the SD Card.

Now I want to create a list of the various projects on the main screen for the user to select from, but I'm not 100% sure how to go about this. My first thought was to have an XML file called `Projects List` which lists all the projects that have been created. But I just can't seem to figure out a way to update an XML file every time a new project is created, and this is where I was looking for some help.

Can someone please help me to understand how to update an XML file?

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Let your creativity and software design knowledge make the right choice for your current project. If you are in doubt read up. When you make a choice think about the pros and cons of using that approach and compare it with other approaches. Look at that choice in the light of all the requirements of your project.

Comment: For storing all the projects;

 - You can can store the list in the xml file as your said. That means every time you want to create a new project you have to append a new entry to that xml file. Similarly when you delete a project you have to remove that entry. if your file becomes too big the parsing can be expensive as well. 
 - You can also store the list of projects in a sqlite database. 

Again these are just a few options. make the choice that fits best and satisfies the requirements of your project. Goodluck.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and your response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My first thought was to have an XML file called Projects List which
>   lists all the projects that have been created.

Instead of doing this, why not simply see how many xml files there were created(corresponding to projects created)? I assume that, now, you're saving those project in a folder created by you on the `SD Card` so when it's time to show that information to the user simple check your projects folder, see how many there are(get the names, get a reference to those xml files so you could open them on a user action etc) and present them to the user.

This would be a lot simpler then implementing the logic to update a xml each time the user does some changes to the projects, not to mention the case when the user might delete those xml files when your app is not running.

Comment: As I said to RenegadeAndy, thank you for response and what you are suggesting is much easier than what I was trying to do.  I am definitely going to do this instead.  Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, didn't want to create a whole new thread so just thought I would ask here? How would I go about populating a list view using the method you described above?

Comment: @Greyham You should post a question for each problem you have but please make some efforts to solve on your own the problem before asking. Check the `File` ( http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html ) class on android(create an instance with the path to your project folder on the SD Card). That class has a `list` method that returns an array with the names of the files in that folder. Use that array to populate the `ListView` with an `ArrayAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following.

The user create some projects - and for each project you have an xml file.

You check for all xml files - grab a bit of info from each, and build a ListView :
[Android listview example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/)

From here you can create a custom adapter which would do the hard work of working out what information you need from each XML file and then when the user clicks the 'browse projects button' they can see all projects in a listview?

Comment: Thank you for you response.  That does sound a lot easier than what I was trying to do, seems so obvious now.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, please tick the green arrow and the tick icon next to the answer you prefer - helps to keep helpful people answering questions!